# Physically Separating Secure and Non Secure Web Requests

Tags: http, architecture, web-applications, https

We have been doing some research into physically isolating the secure and non-secure sections of our web application into two applications.  All "http" requests would be served by one server (or cluster) and all "https" requests would be served by another server (or cluster).

The reason that we are looking into this is partially for the survivability of the application.  Since the secure section of the application is revenue generating we could, for example, have a larger and/or more powerful cluster to serve the requests.  Conversely, when we upgrade the hardware in the secure application, it could be re-purposed to serve the non-secure site - basically extending the life of the servers.

Has anyone worked with this approach?  We had an RFP out to a (well known) vendor last year for an architectural assessment and this was one of the possible paths that was recommended.  While I see the potential upside, I worry about things such as maintenance, deployment, version control, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending how your app is architected, it seems to me that if you used virtualisation / load balancing you could have the same benefits of guaranteed resources and isolation for the paid area, while also being able to dynamically burst resources to deal with spikes in load in either area. Your current proposal allows you to guarantee and prioritise resources, but it may result in some of them being idle.

Plus it would be easier to manage load through configuration, as it would then be a pure deployment issue and an entirely separate concern. You'd also be more independent of your hardware upgrade path as you'd just be adding/assigning virtual machines to the new hardware.

Comment: This is more along the lines of the approach that we had recommended, as well.  I completely agree that this is the preferred approach - it is now a matter of building an argument to dissuade the company from following the approach.  :-)